# Form doesn’t submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I’ve a form like this with my Javascript code:

```js
var btnSubmit = document.getElementById("submit");
btnSubmit.addEventListener("click", sending);

function sending() {
  btnSubmit.disabled = true;
  btnSubmit.value = "Sending...";
  btnSubmit.form.submit(); //<----- this doesn't do anything!!!
}
```

```html
<form id="form_save" action="/ValidatePicsServlet" method="post">
  <!-- more inputs -->
  <button id="submit" type="button">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

As you can see, the last line doesn’t do anything, and the data is not submitted.

Where am I wrong?

EDIT: I'm so so sorry! I had a mistake copying the code. The eventListener actually called sending function, that was right. I'm embarrased...

Comment: you function name should be 'send'

Comment: Giving the button an ID of *submit* may mask the form's submit method (a name of *submit* certainly does) so it can't be called. Forms can be submitted without clicking the button, so put the listener on the form's submit handler, change the button to type submit and remove the ID.

Comment: @Xufox, that was a mistake of mine... fixed, but it doesn't repeair what I wanted to repeair :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because form.submit is override by the submit element you've created inside the form.
Just change the id of your button and it's work like a charm.

```js
var btnSubmit = document.getElementById("submit-button");
btnSubmit.addEventListener("click", sending);

function sending() {
  btnSubmit.disabled = true;
  btnSubmit.value = "Sending...";
  btnSubmit.form.submit();
}
```

```html
<form id="form_save" action="/ValidatePicsServlet" method="post">
  <!-- more inputs -->
  <button id="submit-button" type="button">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @William KLEIN, that's it! :)

Answer (score -2):

Try adding the 'submit' type to your form button.

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: @Xufox—but the OP has `type="button"`, so it's not a submit button.